# updated Cyanogenmod 10.2 to 11 and now can't access sdcard0

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery

Hey guys hoping someone can help me with this:

I just updates Cyanogenmod from 10.2 to 11 on a Samsung Galaxy S2 and I can not seem to access SD card 0. The camera does not cuntion and in the file viewer sdcard 0 acts like an empty folder.

In clockwork mod I can see that my files are still there I just can't seem to access them (its like the os doesn't have read/write access or its unmounted).

I have tried: - reverting back - mounting the sd card manually in clockworkmod then booting - soft reset - hard reset - clearing data and resetting phone to factory through clockwork

I am out of ideas. Anyone know this? By googling I can see this is not an uncommon issue but I did not find a solution that helped

Comment: Did you format partition while installing cm11? Also can you check in Settings-> Storage. Do you have SDcard listed there?

Comment: I appreciate the enthusiasm but this post was from March last year...